# SurfaceView or Canvas

Tags: android, android-imageview, surfaceview

I'm making a game that involves the user tilting the device to move an ImageView, which is a picture of Hang Glider around through gates. Would it be faster/better to use a SurfaceView, or a Canvas? I would be updating the display rather frequently (~10 milliseconds) or so.

Comment: Most devices are limited to ~60fps, which is 16.7ms.  Is the hang glider image static or do you need to update it (i.e show it tilting up / down)?  I'm not entirely sure what you're asking -- `Canvas` can be used to draw on `SurfaceView`, so it's not either/or.  You can also draw with OpenGL ES, though that has a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: The hang glider image is static, what technique/method would you recommend?

Comment: At 60fps you'll want hardware acceleration enabled for View rendering; see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html for tips.  If you can get the performance you want from simple image drawing calls, stick with it; if not, you can try `SurfaceView` + `Canvas` rendering.  I don't think you'll need to use GL.

Answer (score 0):

i use

```
extends View
```

and it is very quick.

Comment: i use extends View with canvas and its very quick